# how to get wednesday date between two dates in php

Tags: php

need to obtain all wednesday dates between two dates. For ex
start and end date=

```
01/07/2019 - 01/25/2019
```

expected result=

```
01/09/2019,
01/16/2019,
01/23/2019
```

can i use  `if ($startDate->format('w') == 2) {}`
condition to filter wednesdays and push into array. any method to get the result?

Comment: you can mark answer as valid answer if it finds useful

Answer (score 2):

Use [DatePeriod Class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php). date period allows iteration over a set of dates and times, recurring at regular intervals, over a given period.

```
$period = new DatePeriod(
     new DateTime($date1),
     new DateInterval('P1D'),
     new DateTime($date2)
);

$cnt = 0;
foreach ($period as $key => $value) {

    if($value->format('D') == 'Wed'){
        $wed[$cnt] = $value->format('m/d/Y');
        $cnt++;
    }   
}
```

Output

```
[0] => 01/09/2019
[1] => 01/16/2019
[2] => 01/23/2019
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$from_date ='01/07/2019';
$to_date ='01/25/2019';

$from_date = new DateTime($from_date);
$to_date = new DateTime($to_date);

$get_date = array();
for ($date = $from_date; $date <= $to_date; $date->modify('+1 day')) {
   if($date->format('l') == 'Wednesday'){
        $get_date[] = $date->format('m/d/Y');
   }
}

print_r($get_date);
```

Out put

```
Array ( [0] => 01/09/2019 [1] => 01/16/2019 [2] => 01/23/2019 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get the required output.

```
<?php

$date1 = date("01/07/2019");
$date2 = date("01/25/2019");
$day1 = date('D', strtotime($date1));
$period = new DatePeriod(New Datetime($date1),New DateInterval('P1D'),New DateTime($date2));

$cnt = 0;
foreach($period as $key => $value ){

  if($value->format('D') == 'Wed'){
        $wed[$cnt] = $value->format('m/d/Y');
        echo $wed[$cnt];        
        $cnt++;
        echo '<BR>';  

    } 

}



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the base `DateTime` class and instead of checking every day, just keep adding 7 days to the date and check if it is still less than the end date.  The only additional logic is that if the start date is a Wednesday, then use this date, otherwise get the next Wednesday...

```
$fromDate = new DateTime('01/02/2019');
if ( $fromDate->format('D') != 'Wed')   {
    $fromDate->modify("next wednesday");
}
$toDate = new DateTime('01/25/2019');
do {
    echo $fromDate->format("m/d/Y").PHP_EOL;
} 
while ( $fromDate->modify(""+7 day"") < $toDate );
```

outputs...

```
01/02/2019
01/09/2019
01/16/2019
01/23/2019
```